# package.json script conditional

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have a node script that checks for some conditions. Lets call it `condition.js`. I have another script which runs my program, lets call it `runner.js`. `runner.js` is referenced by a command in my `package.json` file under scripts as well `condition.js` with their own commands. I want the `condition.js` to run before `runner.js`. If a certain condition is true (it checks a string for something) in the `condition.js` when it runs, I want the second script to run after it. If it is not true, I don't want the second script to run. How can I do this in `package.json`?

Comment: Write a third script, put **it** in `package.json`, and have it run the other two accordingly.

Comment: That makes sense but I can't do it more explicitly to show the relation between the two scripts?

Comment: No, you can't. It's a JSON file - it's not intended to do a bunch of heavy lifting on the logic front. Let your single script do the showing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `condition.js` you need to `exit()` the Node process with a non-zero exit code. Then in your `package.json` file you can check whether to execute the second script based on the exit code (zero or not):

In your `condition.js` file:

```
if (true) {  // use your actual condition
  process.exit(128);
}
```

Then, in your `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "special": "node condition.js && node runner.js"
  }
}
```

Now you can run `npm run special` from the command line, the `runner.js` file will only run if `condition.js` exits with a zero code (which is the default if the node execution ends normally).

Comment: Didn't work for me. Whenever a non-zero exit code is returned from condition.js, the entire npm process fails.

Comment: @bar Yes, that's what the `&&` means... you could alter this code to ignore the outcome of the previous statement like so: `node condition.js; node runner.js`

Comment: Of course, but ignoring the outcome of the `condition.js` defeats the purpose, doesn't it??

Comment: I'm really confused by your comments. The entire point of `condition.js` is to STOP the `npm run special` process intentionally if it returns a non-zero exit code. That's literally its purpose. Sooo... it sounds like it did work for you, but you want something else?